# stateMachine vs Activity

Tags: uml, state-machine

I'm a little confused about difference between state machine diagram and activity diagram in this specific situation.
In a follow simple schema, can you distinguish between activity or state machine diagram? The symbols are present in both diagrams.
[image: ambiguous diagram]

thanks

Mauro

Comment: Excellent question! I've never used that notation for state machines, and ignored that part of the spec. You'd have to look at the spec to determine if that diagram is indeed a valid state machine. If it is, you would have to have the model, not just the diagram, and inspect the meta-types. Models exist to communicate, so why anyone would anyone choose to make such an ambiguous diagram?

Comment: I tried a bit with EA and it seems that the Receive is only present in SMs while the Send is present in both SM and AD.

Comment: Of course, according to the UML spec, you can use elements on any diagram type. EA creates Send and Receive with metatype Event in both AD and SM. So the answer to the question is actually: no, you can not tell by just looking at the diagram.

Comment: Thanks for response. I am studing for OCUP2 foundamental and I have found this diagram in a question. The first possible answer is "element A, B and C are Action" (or something like that). So, if this is a activity diagram, the answer is correct. If this is a state machine diagram i think no, because A and C are State and not Action

Comment: Thomas, Sparx EA implementation tells us nothing about UML itself.

Comment: @JimL. I know, but they are "rather" accurate in the implementation and give a good point for a start. Anyway, I found the solution in the specs. Mauro: Action and State have the same form, B is definitely none, it's an Event. This kind of question affirms that those tests are absolute nonsense ;-)

Comment: Mauro, there's no "something like that" in OCUP exams. You need to be very precise, analyze all possibilities and be sure why this particular answer is correct. They put some tricks and ambushes here and there. Of course it might be difficult at the exam itself but don't have such loose approach when learning to it.

Comment: Ister, I took The exam And I found this question. The real question is a bit different But The difference is irrilevant. So, my question here is pretty accurate. please note  that I like to discuss uml although I know that things are not useful in the real world.

Answer (score 3):

I now can confirm that you can't tell. On p. 331 of the UML 2.5 spec you find an example of the receive event used in a SM. The very same symbol is used on p. 409 for an AD.

So the answer is: no, you can't tell which diagram type is being used from the above example.

And more generally (from the Annex on p. 683):

> **NOTE.** This taxonomy provides a logical organization for the various major kinds of diagrams. However, it does not preclude mixing different kinds of diagram types, as one might do when one combines structural and behavioral elements (e.g., showing a state machine nested inside an internal structure). Consequently, the boundaries between the various kinds of diagram types are not strictly enforced.

Comment: Ister, I took The exam And I found this question. The real question is a bit different But The difference is irrilevant. So, my question here is pretty accurate. 
please know that I like to discuss uml although I know that things are not useful in the real world.

Comment: Not sure why you comment here ?!

Answer (score 2):

No, sometimes (like in a given example) you can't tell based only on shapes. However

- usually you know upfront which diagram it is so it's not a problem actually
- the names will be different. States will have nouns while actions/activities as behaviours are named with verbs
- especially on SM usually there are other elements that make it distinguishable: events triggering, action within states (entry/do/exit), actions run on transitions, SM specific elements like history
- while signal receipt/send signals are allowed in SM they are hardly ever used